# Related List not visible for selection from Page Layout

Tags: lookup, related-list, page-layout

I have a custom object called `Partner__c`

It has two lookup relationships to `Contact` standard object as shown below.

[image]

But in Page Layout I am unable to see the Contact object available in the Related List.

[image]

I assumed that if you have a lookup relationship in Y object  to X object, then X object can be exposed as a Related List to Y object.

For Example

```
Y.Foreign_Key = X.Primary_Key
```

Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the lookup is from Partner to Contact, you'll see only fields on the "child" side of the relationship. If you go to Setup > Customize > Contacts > Page Layouts, you can add both related lists (Billing Partners and Business Partners, or whatever you called them) to your contacts' related list section. From your example, `Y.Foreign_Key = X.Primary_Key`, `Y.Foreign_Key` appears a field on `Y`, but appears as a child relationship (related list) on `X`.